# C# ZMQ Socket.SetSockOpt SocketOpt.LINGER - What is the valid options?

Tags: c#, zeromq

```
        using (var context = new Context(1))
        {
            using (Socket socket = context.Socket(SocketType.XREQ))
            {

                socket.SetSockOpt(SocketOpt.LINGER, 100ul);

                socket.Connect("tcp://somewhere:5566");


                string content = "test message";

                socket.Send(content, Encoding.Unicode);
                string message = socket.Recv(Encoding.Unicode);
                Console.WriteLine("Received reply: " + message);
            }
        }
```

I've tried longs, ulongs and byte arrays and I can not find a value that does not lead to an "illegal argument" exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the [clrzmq2](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2) library sources ([Socket.cs](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs)) there are 4 overloads of the SetSocketOpt() method with [long](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs#L277), [ulong](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs#L233), [byte array](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs#L248) or [integer](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs#L262) parameter. To specify linger period for socket shutdown you shoud use integer parameter.
Anyway, I suggest you use the [Socket.Linger](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/blob/master/clrzmq/Socket.cs#L835) property to avoid any possible dismissing.

Comment: Ah, I don't have that option (either Socket.Linger or setSocketOps(int), I must be a version of so behind. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, these methods and option will be added in March of 2011. I believe you can add a helper methods in your code based on this [commit](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/commit/705ba52bfb20a07caf71fa9641f03d20f2bfe7ac).